# How to start carousel other then first item on page loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, owl-carousel

In certain case i want to start the owl carousel from >3 item i.e carousel by defult shows item from 3rd number.. i have seen the documentation their is no such customization option available.How i can achieve this.

Answer (score 10):

in `own carousel-2`**:**

```
owl.owlCarousel({
    startPosition: 2
});
```

Answer (score 3):

There's `jumptTo` method on it, you can call it right after creating the own carousel :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var owl = $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

        autoPlay: 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds

        items : 4,
        itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
        itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3]

    });

    // Now move the carousel to the third item.
    owl = $("#owl-demo").data('owlCarousel');
    owl.jumpTo(3);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways how you can achieve this.

1. You can use Options that are served by the owl-carousel

**startPosition**
Type: Number/String
Default: 0

Start position or URL Hash string like '#id'.

```
            $(".owl-one").owlCarousel({
                startPosition: 0 // 1, 2, 3 
            })
```

2. You can use Events

**to.owl.carousel**
Type: triggerable
Parameter: [position, speed]
Goes to position.

```
 $('.owl-one').trigger("to.owl.carousel", [2, 200]);
```